# CSS and JS not rendering correctly on webpage hosted via BlueHost

Tags: javascript, html, css, bluehost

First time to use Bluehost. I am wondering why my CSS and JS are not rendering correctly.

This is how my public_html folder looks like:

[image]

My assets folder contains CSS and JS folders.

I don't think I made a mistake in terms of the link I've included in the index.html file for the CSS:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">`

Is there a step I may have missed? How can I get my page to load properly, with CSS and JS?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS looks correct:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">`

Do you have a link to the page? Or a print screen from the inspector tool.

For JS, insert it at the bottom of your page, before the closing body tag, like this:

`<script src="assets/js/myscriptfilename.js"></script>`

Edit: Also be aware that Bluehost may have caching activated on the server. You need to either flush that cache from within their admin panel/cpanel/directadmin or just wait for a while until the cache refreshes by itself. Cache means it may load old files with wrong paths to your script or css.